React with Spinner
I do have a Spinner working in the application but I don't think it's implementation is quite right.
The Spinner does show up when loading/reloading the page.  I used some examples I found searching but I find it odd that I must set isDataLoading=true and then isDataLoading=false in the "setTimeout" which is opposite of the examples.
The search is quick since it's just local data that I'm using and not using a Fetch to obtain the data.  The problem I have is I think the Spinner should show when the "Employees" button is clicked since it's pulling in all the data.  It doesn't so I don't think the Spinner is implemented correctly.
Solution: Show the Spinner when loading/reloading the data or when clicking the "employees" button to display all employees.  If searching for partial names then I believe the page is quick enough that a Spinner doesn't need to show but can if needed.
SearchText - Input field for searching for employees.  Employee button to display all employees.
SearchResults - Display the results of search or all employees.
Data (3 test records out of 2K)

const data = [{
  "ROW_NUMBER": 1,
  "PIDM": 991,
  "NAME": "Elvis Presley",
  "PHONE": "999-999-9999",
  "EMAIL": "<a href=mailto:nothing-to-see-here@nowhere.edu>test<\u002fa>",
  "CAMPUS": "Main 1",
  "DEPARTMENT": "Eng /Read /Frgn Lang/ IDS / Comm.",
  "JOBTITLE": null,
  "SEARCHTYPE": null,
  "SEARCHHEADER": null
}, {
  "ROW_NUMBER": 2,
  "PIDM": 992,
  "NAME": "James Dean",
  "PHONE": "999-999-9999",
  "EMAIL": "<a href=mailto:nothing-to-see-here@nowhere.edu>test<\u002fa>",
  "CAMPUS": "Main 2",
  "DEPARTMENT": "Instructional Resources",
  "JOBTITLE": "Lead Librarian-Systems",
  "SEARCHTYPE": null,
  "SEARCHHEADER": null
}, {
  "ROW_NUMBER": 3,
  "PIDM": 993,
  "NAME": "Marilyn Monroe",
  "PHONE": "999-999-9999",
  "EMAIL": "<a href=mailto:nothing-to-see-here@nowhere.edu>test<\u002fa>",
  "CAMPUS": "Main 3",
  "DEPARTMENT": "Housekeeping",
  "JOBTITLE": "Custodian",
  "SEARCHTYPE": null,
  "SEARCHHEADER": null
}];


SearchText (Input field for searching and Employee Button for Loading all Employees)

import { useState } from 'react';
import { faMagnifyingGlass, faPeopleGroup, faBuildingUser, faArrowsRotate } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import utilStyles from '../styles/utils.module.css';

const SearchText = ({ cards, setSearchResults }) => {

  const [enteredText, setEnteredText] = useState("")

  const onFormSubmit = (event) => {

    event.preventDefault();

  }
  
  const onChange = (event) => {

    const fields = ['NAME', 'CAMPUS', 'DEPARTMENT', 'JOBTITLE'];
    const query = event.target.value.toLowerCase();

    //if (!event.target.value) setSearchResults(cards);

    (event.target.value) || setSearchResults(cards);

    const filterData = (cards, fields, query) => {
      return cards.filter(record => fields.some(field => record[field]?.toLowerCase().includes(query)));
    };

    setEnteredText(event.target.value);
    setSearchResults(filterData(cards, fields, query));

  }

  const onEmployees = (event) => {
    setEnteredText("");
    setSearchResults(cards);

  }

  const onReset = (event) => {
    setEnteredText("");
    setSearchResults(cards);

  }


  return (
      
    <>
      
      <form id='EmployeeSearchText' onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
        <div className="container-fluid p-3">
          <div id='Row1' className={`row ${utilStyles.divPadding}`}>
            <div id='Row1Column1' className="col">
              <div id='SearchText-container' className={utilStyles.searchBar}>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMagnifyingGlass} className={utilStyles.icon} />
                <input id='SearchText' type="text" name="SearchText" placeholder="Search Last Name; First Name; Campus; Deparment....." value={enteredText} onChange={onChange} className={`form-control ${utilStyles.inputField} ${utilStyles.inputPadding}`} />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className='text-center'>
            <div id='Row2' className={`row ${utilStyles.divPadding}`}>
              <div id='Row2Column1' className="col">
                <div id='Employees-container'>
                  <button id='EmployeeListing' type="button" onClick={onEmployees} className={utilStyles.btnYellow}>Employees&nbsp;&nbsp;<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPeopleGroup} /></button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id='Row2Column2' className="col">
                <div id='DepartmentListing-container'>
                  <button id='DepartmentListing' type="button" className={utilStyles.btnYellow}>Department Listing&nbsp;&nbsp;<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBuildingUser} /></button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id='Row2Column3' className="col">
                <div id='SearchTextReset-container'>
                  <button id='SearchTextReset' type="button" onClick={onReset} className={utilStyles.btnGrey}>Reset&nbsp;&nbsp;<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowsRotate} /></button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>     
      
    </>
  
  )
}

export default SearchText;


SearchResults (Display the results from the search or display all the employees)

import { useState } from 'react';
import { RotatingLines } from "react-loader-spinner";
import parse from 'html-react-parser';
import { faPhone, faEnvelope } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import utilStyles from '../styles/utils.module.css';

const SearchResults = ({ searchResults }) => {

  const [isDataLoading, setIsDataLoading] = useState(true);

  setTimeout(() => {
    setIsDataLoading(false);
  }, 2);

  const Loader = () => {
    return (
      <RotatingLines
        strokeColor="#51abff"
        strokeWidth="5"
        animationDuration="0.75"
        width="100"
        visible={true}
      />
    )
  }

  const emp = searchResults.map(employee =>
    <div className="col col-12 col-sm-6 col-xl-4 mb-4">
      <div className="col-12 mb-4">
        <div className={`card ${utilStyles.cardBody}`}>
          <div className="card-body">
            <div className={`${utilStyles.ribbonLight} ${utilStyles.ribbonBottomRight}`}><span>{employee.CAMPUS}</span></div>
            <h3 className="card-title card-name">{employee.NAME}</h3>
            <h6 className={`${utilStyles.cardJobtitle} mb-2`}>{employee.JOBTITLE}</h6>
            <p className={`${utilStyles.cardText} ${utilStyles.cardDepartment}`}>{employee.DEPARTMENT}</p>
            <div>
              <p className={utilStyles.cardTextBottom}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPhone} className={utilStyles.cardTextIcons} /><span className={utilStyles.cardPhoneEmail}>W:</span>{employee.PHONE}</p>
              <p className={utilStyles.cardTextBottom}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEnvelope} className={utilStyles.cardTextIcons} /><span className={utilStyles.cardPhoneEmail}>W:</span>{parse(employee.EMAIL)}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
  );
  
  const content = emp?.length ? emp : <article><p className={`${utilStyles.cardResultCount}`}>No Matching Results</p></article>
  

  return (
    
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">{isDataLoading ? (<div style={{width: "100px", margin: "auto"}}><Loader /></div>) : content}</div>
    </div>

  );

}

export default SearchResults;



I'm not sure if you're aware, but in JS setTimeout works in milliseconds, so setTimeout(()=>{...},2) is practically instant.

At one point I had the value at 2000.  I'm thinking the loader is showing for "x" milliseconds because of the "visible=true" value in the Loader.  I think my code is all wrong for using a Loader.  Just not sure what to change.

Ok, I was able to fix my code and get the spinner working as it should.
What did I do?
Solution:
I switched to using a "Spinner" from react-bootstrap.  Added "const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);" to the App page and passed that down.
The code now works as it should with showing a "Spinner" before displaying the results.
App

import { useState } from 'react';
import { employees } from './search-data/data.js';
import SearchHeader from './search-header/page.js';
import SearchText from './search-text/page.js';
import SearchResults from './search-results/page.js';

function App() {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState(employees);
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState(employees);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  
  return (
    
    <>
    
    <SearchHeader />
    <SearchText cards={cards} setIsLoading={setIsLoading} setSearchResults={setSearchResults} />
    <SearchResults setIsLoading={setIsLoading} isLoading={isLoading} searchResults={searchResults} />
    
    </>

  );

}

export default App;


SearchResults

import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Spinner } from "react-bootstrap";
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import parse from 'html-react-parser';
import { faPhone, faEnvelope } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import utilStyles from '../styles/utils.module.css';

const SearchResults = ({ setIsLoading, isLoading, searchResults }) => {
  var employees;

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }, 100);
  });

  {(searchResults?.length !== 0) &&
    
   (employees = searchResults.map(employee =>
      <Card className={`col col-12 col-sm-6 col-xl-4 mb-4 ${utilStyles.cards}`} style={{ width: '25rem' }}>
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title className={`${utilStyles.ribbon} ${utilStyles.ribbonLight} ${utilStyles.ribbonBottomRight}`}><span>{employee.CAMPUS}</span></Card.Title>
          <Card.Title as="h3" className="card-title card-name">{employee.NAME}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Title as="h6" className={`${utilStyles.cardJobtitle} mb-2`}>{employee.JOBTITLE?.length ? employee.JOBTITLE : <br />}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Title className={`${utilStyles.cardText} ${utilStyles.cardDepartment}`}>{employee.DEPARTMENT}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Title className={`${utilStyles.cardText} ${utilStyles.cardTextBottom}`}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPhone} className={utilStyles.cardTextIcons} /><span className={utilStyles.cardPhoneEmail}>W:</span>{employee.PHONE}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Title className={`${utilStyles.cardText} ${utilStyles.cardTextBottom}`}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEnvelope} className={utilStyles.cardTextIcons} /><span className={utilStyles.cardPhoneEmail}>W:</span>{parse(employee.EMAIL)}</Card.Title>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
  
    ))
  };


  return (
    
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        {!isLoading && (employees?.length ? employees : <article><p className={`${utilStyles.cardResults}`}>No Matching Results</p></article>)}
        {isLoading && (<div style={{width: "100px", margin: "auto"}}><Spinner as="span" variant="secondary" aria-hidden="true" animation="border" style={{ width: "4rem", height: "4rem" }}/></div>)}
      </div>
    </div>

  );

}

export default SearchResults;


These changes seemed to correct my issues.
